# Angular-cli start new project fail

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I create a new project with angular-cli (angular 5), but the start is fail (it's work last week):

```
ERROR in C:/Users/Dev/CoursAngular/jsjobs/src/main.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\src\main.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
ERROR in C:/Users/Dev/CoursAngular/jsjobs/src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\src\polyfills.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
    at plugin.done.then (C:\Users\Maison\Documents\Dev\jsjobs\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

node -v: 8.11.1

Npm -v: 5.6.0

ng -v: 1.7.4

Some update gone wrong ?

Thanks you

Comment: can you please tell us the exact steps you took that caused this error? (which commands etc)

Comment: i just create new project: #ng new project, #cd project and #npm start, I use angular 5

Comment: Can you show the tsconfig contents file and check that main.ts and polyfills.ts files are in the project folder ?

Comment: my tsconfig do not content these 2 files

Comment: i change work directory and it works now.....

Comment: and today the new directory doesn't work.....

Comment: OK i know why!! I can't start if i open Visual Studio Code before run the application....

Comment: I've got this error because my project directory had a symbolic link (NTFS junction) in its path. I.e. I opened c:\dev\test\test.sln, where c:\dev is a junction pointing to c:\users\ivan\documents\dev. Npm does not like this setup, one should always use the full path without junctions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i know why!! I can't start if i open Visual Studio Code before run the application....

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem with using Visual Studio Code.  I'm not sure if this is the same because @kaneda descriptions are a little sparse, but my search lead to this page and this might help others.

Many solutions are discussing changing the tsconfig files but the error and tsconfig files are completely unrelated to this fix.  My issue was a problem with case sensistivity between directory names (e.g.: /Models/ vs /models/) and if any .ts file had an import that varied in case to the directory.

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8284

Specifically see  **stuartkuentzel commented on Nov 3, 2017** entry.

I think this might be associated to this issue as a result of the two comments:

> i change work directory and it works now.

and

> I can't start if i open Visual Studio Code before run the application

I think the first comment might correlate to my scenario in that I was doing housekeeping to standardize my naming conventions and changed a file from all lower case to camel.  The class names were correct, but there was one instance where my import was still all lower case.

The second comment correlates to something I observed with Visual Studio Code, where I closed the IDE down and re-opened it to see that the file was still being displayed in all lower case.  I'm not sure why and I couldn't find any reference to the file in any project files, but it showed me that VSC might not correctly refresh its interface to show other changes that might have been made.

While this solution might not be the same as kaneda, the search on the error message and Visual Studio Code lead me to this page, and it might help others.

Confirming, this had nothing to do with changing tsconfig files.